# Vim - Unite file_rec : missing files

Tags: vim, unite.vim

I just installed Unite (with vundle), so that my `.vimrc` has 1 only new line:`Plugin 'unite.vim'`

Then I do this:

1. I open `vi` from my current dir (which has some nested subdirs & files)
2. I run    `:Unite file_rec`
3. In the results-window I enter `i`
4. I continue writing some text (ex. `pdf`, but the problem occurs for any searched text)
5. the results change on the fly but they are always a subset of a full set of files retrieved by a normal: `find . -iname '*pdf*'`

(I know that the directories are not listed as candidate results, but I cannot see in the results, normal files (they are neither symlinks nor special-permission files). Moreover I refreshed the result/cache with `<C-L>`, but still the result remains partial.

Isn't this `file_rec` search, a `Unite` feature I should expect working out of the box ?
If not, which is the best option to overwrite the default behavior and make `Unite` search as a normal (`find . -iname '*xxxxx*'`) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. There is a builtin value for the max number of results `(g:unite_source_rec_unit)`
the documentation says:
`The default value is 1000(windows environment), 2000(other)`

```
    [...]If you increase the value, |unite-source-file_rec| will be
    faster but it will block Vim for a long time.
    Note: This option does not work in
    |unite-source-file_rec/async| source.
```